# Ways to express "what's happening", "what happened", or "what will happen" in French

Tags: grammaire, traduction, subordonnées, formulation-idiomatique

I've been having trouble looking for ways to say "what happened", "what's happening", and "what will happen" in French.

I feel it's "Ce qui s'a passé", "Ce qui se passe", and "Ce qui se passera".

Also, can someone clear up interrogative *futur simple* sentence structure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were close - "Ce qui se passe" and "Ce qui se passera" are both good, colloquial structures. You could also use "Ce qui va se passer" as an alternative.

"Ce qui **s'a** passé," however, is incorrect because "se passer" is a reflexive verb, which means that in the past tense it uses "être."

So you get "Ce qui **s'est** passé" instead.

Now, if you are *asking* "What happened," "What's happening," or, "What will happen?" you will need to change those phrases a little bit, using [interrogative structure](https://francais.lingolia.com/en/grammar/tenses/le-futur-simple).

In the order you asked, you would say:

> "**Qu'est** qui s'est passé ?"
>
> "**Qu'est-ce** qui se passe ?"
>
> "**Qu'est-ce** qui se passera ? / **Qu'est-ce** qui va se passer ?"

Comment: Ah merci :D J'ai oublé que passer est un verbe reflechi(?)

Comment: @MarcoRubenAbuyuanLlanes De rien ! Ce sont des verbes *pronominaux* ;)

Comment: A noter qu'on peut aussi dire la formes "Que se passe-t-il" (aux 3 temps). (cf "Biouman" des Inconnus :D)

Comment: What I personally found useful when learning this is the literal breakdown of the various parts that go into a "Qu'est-ce" structure. Your otherwise excellent answer might be improved further by its inclusion.